# Controlling the cache of a DataGrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I have implemented a virtual-scrolling DataGrid with an underlying QueryReadStore as follows

```
<span dojoType="dojox.data.QueryReadStore" 
      jsId="logsStore" url="./logs.do" requestMethod="post"></span>
<div  class="logsListContainer" 
      style="align: center; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px">
    <table height="100%" id="logs" jsId="logs" class="soria"
           dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="logsStore" 
           rowsPerPage="20" keepRows="20" autoHeight="20"
           query="{action: 'logsList'}" autoRender="false">
```

I can see on the server's log that the rows are fetched by bunches of 20, which is a good thing, but it seems that they are kept in cache on the client side because they are never reread.
This can be a problem when the number of rows is large.
Is there a way to control how many rows are kept in cache? I thought that setting keepRows would do the trick, but obviously it does'nt.

Comment: What version of the QueryReadStore are you using? I'm looking through the current source and it looks like it only caches the last fetch call

Comment: 1.2.3. But your are probably right: it doesn't cache rows as javascript objects, it just leaves the values in the table.
Therefore, I am considering using pagination instead of virtual scrolling.